# Wireshark и AIM

Tags: сеть, сниффер

Добрый вечер!
Пытаюсь перехватить wireshark'ом пакеты icq(v8). В поле протокол по идее всегда должно быть AIM, но вместо этого wireshark пишет SSL. Самое интересное то, что один раз (совершенно случайно видимо) wireshark правильно указал протокол - тобишь aim, при этом никакие настройки не менялись. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы wireshark всегда определял протокол AIM? Или может проблема из-за разных серверов icq?

Comment: вот, нашел решение :)
http://jsaxton.com/fun-with-wireshark-and-aim/

Comment: @markos, как наберете репутацию, напишите сами себе тут решение, чтобы потом можно было пользоваться и другим.